# How to show tab on tab-bar and sidebar in Blackberry 10 native with QML

Tags: tabs, qml, native, blackberry-10

I am trying to develop my application with Tabbed-pane in Blackberry - 10 with Native development. I have 6 Tabs on my Tabbed-pane and i have set property

```
showTabsOnActionBar: true
```

So i can see the tabs on my Tab-bar, so basically i have 6 tabs so it showing 3 Tabs on Tab-bar and other are in Sidebar and when i open Sidebar it shows all 6 tabs in it, but instead of that what i want to do is I want to show 4 tabs on my Tab-bar instead of 3 and when i open a Sidebar it should only show remaining 2 tabs instead of all 6 tabs.

I have tried with

```
ActionBar.placement: ActionBarPlacement.OnBar
ActionBar.placement: ActionBarPlacement.InOverflow
```

but then also i am getting same result, i think this is very simple thing but i don't know how can i achieve this. Let me know if you want anything or don't understand the question properly i will give more explanation and if needed my code also.

Please help me to complete this task. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how the tab side bar is designed to operate. All the tabs will always be there, unless you place them on the action bar, and they all fit on the action bar.

Comment: Okay, So is there any other way through which i can achieve what exactly i want to implement ???

Comment: Indeed, you can write the user interface objects yourself, or find an alternate user interface toolkit that has the objects you want. However a fundamental premise of user interface design is the enforcement of a common look and feel through the objects provided in the API. This is why one can look at a screen capture of an application and usually tell what platform it is running on. The reason for this is to give the user a staring point in knowing how to interact with your application. You can of course choose to differentiate your application from the herd, but that comes with costs.